# Sorting alphabetically in a log?

Tags: java, sorting, logging, interface

Anybody know how to do sorting in logs? I tried using `compareToIgnoreCase` but I only know how to use it with Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringLogInterface log;
        log = new ArrayStringLog("Example Use");
        log.insert("Elvis");
        log.insert("King Louis XII");
        log.insert("Captain Kirk");
        System.out.println(log);
        System.out.println("The size of the log is " + log.size());
        System.out.println("Elvis is in the log: " + log.contains("Elvis"));
        System.out.println("Santa is in the log: " + log.contains("Santa"));
    }
```

Comment: You need to tell us which logging API are you using?

Comment: I assume that code is : http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/ds/bookFiles/ch02/stringLogs/ArrayStringLog.java

Comment: Can you show us how did you use `compareToIgnoreCase` ? What are you exactly trying to achieve? when does have the sorting to happen? while inserting or just before printing? for the latter Melih's answer might help you. Do you have any restrictions regarding the code already provided in the link above?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your code is : http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/ds/bookFiles/ch02/stringLogs/ArrayStringLog.java

firstly add getLog method to ArrayStringLog class :

```
public String[] getLog() {
    return log;
}
```

then sort function is that :

```
Arrays.sort(log.getLog(), new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }
});
```